# C++: Best way to declare a variable to hold the return value of a function?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I believe the following is a relatively common pattern (the exact types used are not important, they're just for example):

```
std::vector<std::string> manufactureVector(int param1, const std::string& param2) {
    std::vector<std::string> returnValue;
    // do some calculation with param1 and param2 to fill in the vector
    return returnValue;
}
```

However, the return type of manufactureVector is mentioned twice, with all of the drawbacks of that sort of redundancy, e.g. any future change has to be made identically in two places, etc. What's the best way to remove this redundancy? I am aware of:

1. Use a typedef. This seems cumbersome if the return type is a one-off, so that the typedef would not be used anywhere else; at the very least, such a typedef adds a line of code.
2. I believe C++20 (and possibly earlier) allows you to change the *first* occurrence of the type (in the function declaration) to `auto` and it will be inferred from what is actually returned. But that doesn't seem to work for declaring the function in a header (where there is no body to infer from) and then defining it in another source file. (Perhaps this is among the reasons to switch to modules?) Moreover, to my eyes at least it's harder to see what the return type of `manufactureVector` actually is if you use `auto` as its return type: I have to find the return statement, and then figure out what the type of that expression is.

Are there other possibly better alternatives to consider? In particular is there any reasonably brief "Incantation" such that

```
MyComplicatedType foo(int p, double q) {
  Incantation returnValue;
  // Here returnValue is a variable of type MyComplicatedType, whatever that type was
  ...
}
```

Ideally, such an Incantation wouldn't have to explicitly use the function name "foo" either, as that would substitute a different (small) bit of redundancy.

(Quite) a while back, GCC had named return values like

```
MyComplicatedType foo(int* ptr, char c) return returnValue { 
  // here returnValue is a newly default-constructed variable
  // of type MyComplicatedType
  ...
  // And in fact having declared the return variable this way,
  // you didn't even need to have the return statement at the end.
}
```

which was exactly the ticket here, in my view, but unfortunately that has been left behind in the dustbin of C++ history. Is there a modern equivalent or substitute? (I am perfectly happy with C++20-only solutions.)

Comment: Not entirely on topic, but I remember that for lambdas, you can explicitly specify the return type with `->`, e.g. `[&](double d) -> double {yadda yadda}`. Maybe there is something akin for common functions too.

Comment: wow, did gcc really do that? do you have a link?

Comment: There is [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) but as it needs the parameter types (because of overload resolution) I don't think this helps.  I think overload resolution will complicate things and make the question impossible to solve.

Comment: How different is this from having to specify the entire function signature, not just the return type, both in the function's declaration and its definition (if it needs to be explicitly declared, as is usual the case).

Comment: @NeilButterworth: E.g. https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/~krabat/FH-Labor/gnupro/2_GNUPro_Compiler_Tools/Using_GNU_CC/gccNamed_Return_Values_in_C.html

Comment: Anyway, the priority of concerns should be what is clear to the reader and future maintainer of the code over what is convenient to the coder. Repeating the type may be inconvenient to the coder, but does no harm to code clarity.

Comment: I think most of the time if you want to change the return type. you'd probably need to rewrite the whole body, the re-declaration is the small problem.

Comment: @Glen thank you -interesting, but horrible, imho.

Comment: @jxh: How does the compiler figure out the template parameter if I just say `std::vector returnValue;` ? Does it look forward to the first use of the vector? What if I push_back a `const char*` rather than a `std::string`? (If you can just point me to a primer on this sort of inferred template argument that would be greatly appreciated.) Also, in my experience redundancy eventually almost always makes code less maintainable, so I think in this case coder convenience and maintainability are aligned...

Comment: @NeilButterworth why horrible? It was both convenient and very readable and captured a very common use case...

Comment: @GlenWhitney Search "template argument deduction". In this particular use case, the return type is echo'd right next to each other with the first local variable at the top of the function, and purpose reflected in the variable name. So the purpose is clear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, there is redundancy between the header and the definition file but (A) not sure how that would be avoided, and (B) isn't that beside the point of this question? Don't see how the existence of other redundancy makes the redundancy I am asking about less bad.

Comment: @Glen not common to me at all. and i despise gcc extensions, particularly when applied as defaults.

Comment: @appleapple OK sure but to have to duplicate the change to the return type in the first declaration only needlessly adds to the work of the change (well, needlessly if there were a way to declare a variable of the return type of the function). Just because a problem is small compared to other effort doesn't mean it's not a problem...

Comment: @GlenWhitney I believe the problem is actually because this is small. and not considered by standard committee (or even gcc) that it worth the effort/language complexity.

Comment: @jxh OK I searched, and I see for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction -- but as far as I can see, all of the deduction there relies on arguments to the initialization, of which there are none in `std::vector returnValue;` Can that really compile correctly? If so, please could you be so kind as to point me toward some exposition of this kind of template argument deduction.

Comment: @appleapple Ah I see your point there. I am just surprised given that I coded heavily in C++ in the early 2000s and coming back now about two decades later I see to my delight so much reduction of redundancy with things like `auto` etc., that I assumed there would be a reasonably convenient way to do this...

Comment: @GlenWhitney You are right, it needs an initialization to deduce the arguments. You could use templates, I suppose. https://tio.run/##RYxLCsMwEEP3PsVANwkhmy7z8SF8AzNxjME/7ElJKbl63TgtVCtJPAlj7DViuRmPdlsUTA@FFBJn/yZTMl7zQspFK@ls6BmVl06BgBkyLcPwXU2X//GcCVhDgKaFF4NTAvbxMknRlnxNRzGewEnjK1Xxph3hKG9crdS59OfhjF13lx8

Comment: And there is `decltype`. https://tio.run/##RYzBCsMgDIbvfYrALkrpZce267tItCI4FU3HyuirL7NusP@U//uSYEqDReSLC@g3bWB@GKSYl@5PCmUX7MKF9Dh@9dzmn4A1RhASXh3UaIOe9mREpUJKeE4NZ0NbDmc72AWCu3LhvIG2NsHBb1y9soWH@vuGfX9VHw

Comment: Ah, yes, but that's exactly why I put a bunch of parameters in all of my examples in the original post; I was aware of decltype, but when there are parameters you have to include all of them in the instance of decltype, making it noticeably more redundant than just naming the return type twice.

Comment: But thanks for the template example. That would be a third method I hadn't thought of. I guess unless I wanted the flexibility of the template for some reason I'd be just as well off with ``` using FooReturn = std::vector<std::string>; auto foo() { FooReturn returnValue; // etc... ```

Comment: @NeilButterworth Perhaps not so common in your code, but common enough overall that there is an entire pending proposal https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p2025r2.html to ensure that this pattern is efficient, and the motivation for the proposal begins by highlighting this pattern, which it calls "construct-cook-return". I found that proposal by following up on all of these comments (thanks, everyone!) but it does not at all address making the declaration of the variable to be construct-cook-returned more convenient...

Answer (score 2):

If the function **doesn't** have overload. you do not need to pass the parameters to get return type.

```
template <auto F>
using return_type_of = decltype(std::function{F})::result_type;

int foo(int p){
    return_type_of<foo> x;
    return x;
}
```

---

* still need type `foo` twice btw.

** in addition to [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) which need the parameter type as well.

Comment: That is definitely a nice addition to the options I listed in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> However, the return type of manufactureVector is mentioned twice

It can even be more than once, once dependent types are involved:

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator b, e;

for (b=returnValue.begin(), e=returnValue.end(); b != e; ++b)
```

or something along these lines.

So now in addition to all of this, this needs changing too.

Often `auto` comes to the rescue here, but not all the time.

> any future change has to be made identically in two places,

Well, the fact that the return type must be explicitly spelled out in more than one place is unavoidable. This is how C++ works.

However it's possible to future-proof changing the return type in two or more places, in most cases.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> manufactured_vector_t;

// ...

manufactured_vector_t manufactureVector(int param1, const std::string& param2) {
    manufactured_vector_t returnValue;

// ...

    manufactured_vector_t::iterator b, e;

    for (b=returnValue.begin(), e=returnValue.end(); b != e; ++b)

// ...

    return returnValue;
}
```

And now if a `std::vector<std::string>` doesn't fit the bill anymore, it needs to be updated in only one place.

It's very likely that some other changes will be required, too. But, at least, this'll take care of that part.